# How to "Turn off password protected sharing" by code

Tags: windows, powershell, settings, password-protection, lan

I would like to be able to achieve the same results as selecting Manage advanced share settings->turn off password protected sharing by using powershell in windows 10.

I am trying to make .ps1 files which when run set the IP, name the computer, enable file sharing, create a folder on the desktop of host or a shortcut on clients, and disable password protected sharing.

Everything is working except disabling password protected sharing

So far I have tried

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters' -Name 'RestrictNullSessAccess' -Value '0'
```

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa' -Name 'everyoneincludesanonymous' -Value '1'
```

as well as

```
net user guest /active:yes
```

RestrictNullSessAccess paired with everyoneincludesanonymous still prompts me for credentials when trying to access the shared folder.

activating guest gives gives the error " not accessible. you might not have permission to access this network resource."

Comment: Does it work when you set these parameters manually ? this doesn't seems to be a PowerShell issue.

Comment: Yes, when I open Advanced share settings and click the radial button turning off password protected sharing everything works as it should. I am unable to figure out a way to do it within powershell to automate the process.

Comment: the manual steps I referred here is about doing the registry setting without script. If its not working when you create those registry entries w/o PowerShell then automated process will also not help.